# Find all occurrences of 5 digits after decimal, add a digit

Tags: vim, regular-expression

I have a space-separated .txt file of numbers:

```
40.766375 -84.267443
40.766355 -84.267463
40.766325 -84.263443
...
```

Occasionally, there is a number in the first column that does not have 6 digits after the decimal:

```
40.76632 -84.263443
```

I want to insert a 0 at the end of each such occurrence, so that I end up with:

```
40.766320 -84.263443
```

There are many rows (over 36000), so I'd like to do this with regex. Any ideas?

EDIT: I think I need something like 
`:%s/\.d{5}/\.d{5}0` 
but I can't quite get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:%s/\(\.\d\{5\}\) /\10 /
```

This can do what you want.

#### Explanation

With `\(\.\d{5\}\)` we capture first occurrence of dot (`\.`) and five digits (`\d\{5\}`). Also, we checks that there are exactly five of them by leaving the space after capture group.

In the second part of substitution, we're using `\1` to get access to the first (and once) capture group, put `0` after it and put a space to the end, because the space was matched by regexp, but didn't transfered to second part.

A bit about the capture groups: `\10` is exactly «capture group number one and zero after it». Thus, you can get access to only eight groups.

Comment: But if it isn't necessary to do it exactly with vim, i can update this solution with using sed. Probably, regexp will become easier, and using it is simpler than running vim and doing it.

Comment: It worked! Thanks @ValeriyKr. What does the /\10 / mean?

Comment: `\(regexp\)` is a capture group. You can access to them with `\N`, where `N` is its number (from left to right). Here i'm capturing dot and five digits, leaving space outside.

Answer (score 0):

As a more general way to force all numbers to have 6 digit after the period, you could do:

```
:%s/\.\d\+/&00000/g
:%s/\.\d\{6}\zs\d*//g
```

The first one adds 5 zeros, and the second one removes all but the first 6 digits after the period. `\zs` is `vim`'s equivalent of `perl`'s `\K` that resets the start of the matched portion.

You can also do things like:

```
 :%s/\d\+\.\d\+/\=printf("%.6f", str2float(submatch(0)))/g
```